# What is meant by $H_*(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I assume that it must mean direct sum of all homology groups. Is is true? Also, is it provided with some kind of product or it's just a group?
A reference would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: I would say that it depends a lot on the context, it could also denote the *-th homology group... If it denotes the direct sum of all homology groups, there is not a natural product associated with it (on the contrary, you can equip the cohomology ring with the Cup product, but for homology this is not the case).

Comment: Where I'm reading this it seems to have some kind of product, and $H_*(\Omega X)$ is reffered to as "Pontryagin algebra". Although I didn't really find much about this algebra in the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, $H_*(\Omega X)$ refers to the direct sum of all of the homology groups.

For relevant internet searches, try "Pontryagin product" or "Pontryagin ring". For example:

- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pontrjagin+ring
- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homology+of+loop+spaces
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_product

Also Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book, Section 3.C, p. 287.